# Identifying a tag belongs to which branch in git

Tags: git, tags, repository, branch, remote-branch

I first did repo sync to a manifest for a branch name myBranch. I then get the tags from

```
git tag -l
```

Now I want to know using git that each tag obtained as a result of git tag -l was actually created on which branch. Please note : I do not want myBranch as the output but the remote branch name on which the tag was created.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the branch from tag name in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754078/how-to-get-the-branch-from-tag-name-in-git)

Answer (score 8):

Keeping aside the fact that branches can be renamed or deleted at any time (without losing any commits, which can still be referenced in the path of another branch), the best you can do is:

- get the branches that contains the commit referenced by the tag

See "[Show the original branch for a commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535251/show-the-original-branch-for-a-commit)", combined with "[Git - how to tell which commit a tag points to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862423/git-how-to-tell-which-commit-a-tag-points-to)".
(Ie, a combination of `git rev-parse <tag>~0` with `git branch --contains <sha1>`)

This has nothing to do with the branch on which the tag *was created*, but rather the branch(es) which *currently reference* said tag.

Answer (score 6):

No such thing. Tags point to commits, and branches point to commits. A single commit can be pointed at (or be a parent of) dozens of different branches; there is no way to narrow down one specific branch as "the owner of this tag". The branch might have been deleted from upstream before you fetched it, and only the commit remains, as another example of why this can't work.

Comment: `A single commit can be pointed at (or be a parent of) dozens of different branches` good point.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this in two ways

---

1. 

Using the solution given by @VonC I was able to identify for the available tags its source branch

```
for tag in $(git tag)
do
    commit=$(git rev-parse $tag~0)
    echo "$tag: $(git rev-parse $commit~0) | branch: $(git branch -r --contains $commit)" | grep branch
done
```

the output will look like

```
qa-test-integrated-v0.0.3d: 382d0553d189a8a1591667a3806ac98d0f11394a | branch:   origin/HEAD -> origin/master
qa-test-integrated-v0.0.3e: 1a5329d611fe15db6704fe1ea3717b62df8c4320 | branch:   origin/HEAD -> origin/master
tag-from-feature-branch: 851cb526e9f9e2c00a3b1e626c010038ecab7428 | branch:   origin/feature/DPTGROGU-0000-support
```

Given the snippet above you can use any bash tool to filter related to a specific branch.

---

2. If you have the name of the branch and want to know which tags belong to that branch we can use a more fancy solution

```
git tag --merged branch
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
branch=$(git for-each-ref | grep ${commit_num} | grep origin | sed "s/.*\///")
```