# How to get the branch from tag name in Git?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-tag

I am trying to get the branch name from a given tag. 
I tried `git describe --tag <tag-name>` but this doesn't provide me any branch name. I tried using `gitk` to show to the tags and branch but gitk doesn't show me the tag. When I list out the tags `git tag -l` I see the tag name exist in the list.

I just want a simple command which can tell me the branch when tag name is provided.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tags and Branches in Git are only Labels pointing to specific snapshot of your files. That being said, Tags ain't linked to a branch, but to a commit.

As so, you have to check which branch contain the commit pointed by your tag, as so:

```
git branch --contains <tag name>
```

Answer (score 2):

A tag is just an alias name for a commit.

That said, this should answer your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2707110/550177

Answer (score 0):

If you know the commit number the tag is linked to, you can find the branch from which the tag was placed from this command:

```
git_branch=$(git for-each-ref | grep ${commit_num} | grep origin | sed "s/.*\///")
```