# How to get a branch name on GitHub action when push on a tag?

Tags: github, github-actions

I trigger my workflow using

```
on:
  push:
    tags:
```

`GITHUB_REF` won't contain a branch name in this case, how could I get it?

Comment: You could use `git branch --contains $GITHUB_REF` or `git_branch=$(git for-each-ref | grep ${commit_num} | grep origin | sed "s/.*\///")` (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/12754078/10871900)

Comment: @dan1st that doesn't work due to the way that github actions checkout works. You will need to add `-r` flag to contains command to make it work. Example provided in my answer.

Answer (score 13):

Basically during a tag creation push, is like if you were to do `git checkout v<tag>` in your local but there's no reference to the original branch. This is why you will need to use the `-r` flag in the git branch contains command.

We get the clean branch with the following command.

```
branch=$(git branch -r --contains ${{ github.ref }}) --format "%(refname:lstrip=3)"
```

Here is a pipeline that creates a branch env

```
name: Tag
on: 
  create:
    tags:
      - v*
jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: checkout source code
      uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Get Branch
      run: |
        branch=$(git branch -r --contains ${{ github.ref }} --format "%(refname:lstrip=3)")
        echo ::set-env name=BRANCH::$branch
    - run: echo ${{ env.BRANCH }}
```

[Working Example](https://github.com/meroware/get-branch-on-tag-created-action/actions/runs/239945471)

**NOTE:** I triggered the above pipeline by creating a tag and pushing it to origin

Comment: Nice solution! I had some issues:
1. `set-env` is deprecated, so I used `echo "BRANCH=$branch" >> $GITHUB_ENV`
2. The output of git branch contains leading whitespace. I used `branch=${raw##*/}` to remove everything before the last slash.

Comment: If you use checkout@v2, only the last commit will be fetched by default, which makes git branch unable to find the current branch. To resolve this, you need to set `fetch-depth: 0` in the checkout@v2 step. See: https://github.com/actions/checkout#Fetch-all-history-for-all-tags-and-branches

Comment: Thanks a lot for this guys, awesome solution.

Comment: Nice solution. Though to note: A tag can be on multiple branches, so raw can contain a number of branches.

Comment: I tried to run "git branch -r --contains ${{ github.ref }}" and it outputs nothing. I have also tried to run "git branch -r" and it outputs nothing too. Is this solution no longer available?

Comment: @samwize see my answer for a version with multiple branches

Answer (score 7):

Building on Edward's answer, here is a modern script which allows getting branch name *and* passing it between jobs, including allowing jobs to be conditionally run based on branch

```yaml
# This only runs for tags, and the job only processes for "master" branch
name: Example

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - "*"

jobs:
  check:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      branch: ${{ steps.check_step.outputs.branch }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Get current branch
        id: check_step
        run: |
          raw=$(git branch -r --contains ${{ github.ref }})
          branch=${raw##*/}
          echo "{name}=branch" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          echo "Branch is $branch."

  job2:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: check # Wait for check step to finish
    if: ${{ needs.check.outputs.branch == 'master' }} # only run if branch is master

    steps:
      - run: echo "Running task..."
```

Comment: FYI, the output capture method will change soon: https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer based on [@Edward Romero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14167216/edward-romero) and [@Ron S.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11986024/ron-s) answers, a big thank to them !

I only added the "multiples branches" handling, because `git branch -r --contains` can returns multiples values (a list of branches)

```
jobs:
  # @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72959712/8179249
  check-current-branch:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      branch: ${{ steps.check_step.outputs.branch }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Get current branch
        id: check_step
        # 1. Get the list of branches ref where this tag exists
        # 2. Remove 'origin/' from that result
        # 3. Put that string in output
        # => We can now use function 'contains(list, item)''
        run: |
          raw=$(git branch -r --contains ${{ github.ref }})
          branch="$(echo ${raw//origin\//} | tr -d '\n')"
          echo "{name}=branch" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          echo "Branches where this tag exists : $branch."

  build-and-push-image:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # Wait for check step to finish
    needs: check-current-branch
    # only run if tag is present on branch 'main'
    if: contains(${{ needs.check.outputs.branch }}, 'main')`
```

---

Output after pushing a tag on a commit that exist only on `main`

```
Branches where this tag exists : main.
```

=> And `build-and-push-image` job is running ! ✅

---

Output after pushing a tag on a commit that exist on `main` and `develop`

```
Branches where this tag exists : develop main.
```

=> And `build-and-push-image` job is running ! ✅

---

*Be careful to use `contains(${{ needs.check.outputs.branch }}, 'main')` and not `contains(needs.check.outputs.branch, 'main')`, it wasn't working for me without that*

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from the `github.event` variable:

```
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - '*'

jobs:
  main:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Echo branch
        run: echo "${{ github.event.base_ref }}"
```

The code results with:

[image]

Comment: That's only for pull_request https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#steps-context

Comment: @user2863275 You mean `github.base_ref` and I wrote `github.event.base_ref`. I used it with the `push`, for sure. It is a working solution, it's in my CI/CD.

Comment: I have it null on a tag push trigger

Comment: @challet Are you sure you use `github.event.base_ref` and not `github.base_ref`? Because they differ. In my case that worked. But I can't assure you for now, it was long ago.

Comment: That seem logical : "AFAIK, from git perspective, the tag has nothing with the branch but it's a pointer to a particular commit regardless of the branch (which is another pointer to another commit) so it's probably not straightforward"

https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/13226