# How To Trigger Reusable GitHub Actions Workflow By Condition

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to trigger different reusable workflows according to target branch name of a created tag. For example if I create a tag from main branch, I want to trigger `run-on-prod-tags.yml` workflow and if the branch name starts with feature, I want to trigger `run-on-stage-tags.yml`. Should I make something like that in order to do that?

```
name: Tag Workflow

on:
    push:
        tags:
            - '*'

jobs:
    check-tag:
        runs-on: docker-runner
        steps:
            -   name: checkout Source Code
                uses: actions/checkout@v3
                with:
                    # Disabling shallow clone is recommended for improving relevancy of reporting
                    fetch-depth: 0

            -   name: Get Branch
                run: |
                    echo ${{ github.ref }}
                    raw=$(git branch -r --contains ${{ github.ref }})
                    branch=${raw##*/}
                    echo "BRANCH=$branch" >> $GITHUB_ENV
            - run: echo ${{env.BRANCH}}
    build-and-deploy:
        needs: [check-tag]
        uses: ./.github/workflows/run-on-${{env.BRANCH}}-tags.yml
```

If I use something like that, when we change file name of reusable workflows', this code will fail. I should use something more robust. Do you have any idea to do that?

Thanks

P.S. Output Of The Script

[image]

Comment: The above workflow is [invalid](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJxlUE1rAyEQvfsr5rCQtqDehT00gbanHEqhl15cmazbJBrU7VK2/vf6kbAsGRB05r3nm2fkGQXsHMqA8CF7+LTueDjZiRBrBIFUl9HressVZO+XVy4Km6cNId+2uw6URnWkCbjgaDqmfPWKAbZOGqVXIm40Av5WrdKWU9s89EOArnCAOqBUWRPkYDw08wxpqMeOOTxAjI93CpXXNnOS4tYN/WC+eLyDodIWhPAYKJqf4rXdvj/vd29CNN3aL735LaTsIVFYRScPpABzhsv+dfeXnOutNXr0AhhndQE+XYP3PGlTa2gSXnRjzIF69ns+/QMnu3UU). You have different reusable workflows for each branch? Have you tested above strategy? Also, what would this (`git branch -r --contains ${{ github.ref }}`) return?

Comment: The code above is kinda psuedo. check-tag job is focused on finding the branch name of created the tag.

Comment: Regarding "**finding the branch name of created the tag**", see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14613605/7670262. Also. in your case, `github.ref` would contain the tag, not branch. And, [`--contains` requires a commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---containsltcommitgt). Did you mean to use [`github.sha`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) instead?

Comment: I updated my code. I am going to share the output of that script. But I want to emphasize the problem of dynamically calling workflow.

Comment: Apart from that, what kind of issues are you facing with that dynamic configuration?

Comment: github_ref = refs/tags/17 and github_ref_name = 17. But my goal is to find branch name from tag. I can't find branch name from 17 (ref_name). I used tihs as reference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63745613/how-to-get-a-branch-name-on-github-action-when-push-on-a-tag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252442/discussion-between-berkin-and-azeem).

Answer (score 0):

As those are two separate jobs, `env` won't work like that. And, if you resort to [set the output parameter](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter), it still won't work because according to [context availability](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#context-availability), `uses` is not listed i.e. no context is available under `uses`.

So, as of now, you may use `if` and its negation as you're currently doing to switch between workflows with hardcoded full paths of the reusable workflows.

Alternatively, you may write a wrapper reusable workflow with inputs to call the respective workflow internally to hide the details in the main workflow.