# How to see which branch a given change was originally committed to?

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show the original branch for a commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535251/show-the-original-branch-for-a-commit)

I am trying to figure out what happened to a specific file in our Git repo. The file's change history includes changes on several branches and some merges.

Unfortunately, the best output I can get from `git log ... myfile.cs` simply shows a graph of changes with not so much as a single branch name anywhere. It would be great if I could see which branch a given change was committed to.

It appears that this might be something that Git doesn't track. If so, how else might I figure out which branch a change was committed to? If I'm mistaken, how do I persuade `git log` to show the branch names?

(for the record, `--decorate` doesn't do it, presumably because this option only decorates the *last* change on each branch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate : [Show the original branch for a commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535251)

---

Given the numerous operations that can happen to a commit (amend, merge, rebase, imported from origin...), I don't think you can find exactly what you want.

From other SO questions (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419623) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706797)), you can have the branches a commit belongs to :

```
git branch --contains <commit>
```

Comment: In other words, any workflow in which I expect to know the name of the branch at a later stage is doomed to fail in Git?

Comment: I'd rather say : you can always find actions which would break this logic. If you stick to a standard, you can have what you want. A 2 secs idea : add a pre-commit hook which automatically adds the current branch's name to the commit message - I haven't thought about the details, rebasing with such a rule could have some funny effects...

Comment: Thanks. Need to shake my Mercurial habits if I am to keep my hair and sanity...